# Is there any way to include a ViewPager in a listView to transition from one picture to another?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager

I'm currently making an application that is supposed to have a `listView` that contains a `textView` and under the `textView` it is supposed to have one `imageView` that contains many images, but that I can only see one image at a time. I want to be able to swipe on the `imageView` so that I can transition from one picture to another without having to leave the activity. Is there any way to include a `ViewPager` as seen in https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html but have it inside the `listView` or something similar in order to accomplish this? In case it is helpful I have included my custom adapter that currently only supports the text and one image.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Bean> mList;
    private PopupWindow popUpWindow;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Bean> list){
        mContext=context;
        mList=list;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //use convertView recycle
    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_orders, parent, false);
        holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        holder.information= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text and url
    final View finalConvertView = convertView;
    holder.information.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.information_popup, null);
            popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 800,400,true);
            popUpWindow.showAtLocation(finalConvertView.findViewById(R.id.orders), Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);

            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    popUpWindow.dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).resize(500,500).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button information;
    Button close;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not being able to figure out how to do this using the `viewPager`, but I found out how to do it using a `horizontalScrollView`. Here is the link to the question with the answer that I posted.

[Adding a Horizontal Scroll View to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491577/adding-a-horizontal-scroll-view-to-a-listview?noredirect=1#comment64390624_38491577)